# Mysqldump on unencrypted Amazon RDS is creating encrypted .db file

Tags: mysql, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a dump of my RDS data and use it locally.

I've used the command:

`mysqldump -h myhostname.rds.amazonaws.com -u my_username -p my_dbname > ~/Downloads/dump.sql`

When I try to view this data in a tool like DB Browser for sqlite, I get a prompt saying it's encrypted, asking for a password.

I thought maybe it needed to be converted into sqlite first, so I've done this in RazorSQL -> But I still get the same issue. Also, when I try to load the DB into NodeJS's sqlite module I get:

`not able to query Table in SQLite DB Error: SQLITE_NOTADB: file is encrypted or is not a database`

I've checked my RDS settings, and it says:

`Encryption details:
Encryption enabled
No`

So I have no idea what's going on here. Any tips? Does the file extension (`.sql`, `.db` etc) make a difference here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is really no way to salvage this question. You need to read the MySQL documentation to understand what a dump file is. And I'm not sure what you did with RazorSQL, but its docs don't say anything about converting dumpfiles, just databases.

Comment: @kdgregory I'm not sure that first part is true.  The choice of the wrong tools and subsequent misinterpretation of the generic error message *"file is encrypted or is not a database"* are cases of following the wrong rabbits but we do have a question here that does show effort, just not in the right direction.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I think that you gave a good explanation of the OP's confusion (so +1 for that), but imo it's still a bad question and not likely to be helpful to others. Maybe it could be salvaged by deleting the second half (the part about using RazorSQL), leaving a question about why a MySQL dumpfile isn't readable by SQLite. But as-is, it's just "I tried random things and they didn't work." Personally, I think closing is the best option.

Comment: @kdgregory thanks. I see what you're saying, but at the same time, I commend OP for obviating the need to ask, *"what have you tried?"* Also, I didn't expect so many people to find [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44721/11651) useful, where essentially the opposite thing was happening -- the user was piping what turned out to be a sqlite3 database into the `mysql` CLI, as though it were a dump file from `mysqldump`. Coincidentally, this *also* happens return an error message with a suggestion that can lead down the wrong path: `...Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected.`

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to view this data in a tool like DB Browser for sqlite

Sqlite is an entirely different thing than MySQL.  There is very little overlap in tools that can work with both.

You're using a tool that can't be used for the purpose to which you're applying it, so you're getting a confusing error:

```
file is encrypted or is not a database
```

In other words, the tool is unable to make sense of the file, so one of two things is has happened: the file is encrypted *or is not a [sqlite] database [at all]*.

The problem is the latter.

The file is not encrypted.  Even if the RDS instance is encrypted, the generated dump file would still not be encrypted, because encryption in RDS is storage-level encryption of the data, at rest, on the disk volume backing the RDS instance.  Encryption in RDS is transparent to the user.

The problem is that what you have here is a *dump file* -- a series of SQL statements that can be used to reconstruct your database *on another MySQL server*.

Your file is plain text.  You can view it will a text editor.  What you can't do is use the file as a database -- that's something Sqlite can do, because Sqlite stores the database inside a single, transportable file.  MySQL is a different architecture.

You'll need to have the same version (e.g. 5.7.x) of MySQL Server installed locally, and then load this file onto it.

```
shell> mysql [options] < my_dump_file.sql
```

> To reload a dump file written by `mysqldump` that consists of SQL statements, use it as input to the `mysql` client.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html

You can also use query browser tools for MySQL like Toad or Workbench, but a local MySQL Server is required.